# Claiming ownership of an object held by my class' delegate in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm having a problem with the ownership of an ALAsset that is created by my delegate. My delegate is a modal view, and when it is dismissed, it returns an ALAsset, but the asset needs to outlive the delegate.
In the delegate callback, I simply take the ALAsset and place it in an NSMutableArray which is owned by my app's controlling singleton `[OrderManager sharedOrderManager]`

```
-(void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingPictureWithAsset:(ALAsset *)asset    
{
    [[[[OrderManager sharedOrderManager] currentOrder] assets] addObject:asset];
}
```

Later, (after the delegate is dismissed) I build a table view using the assets in the array

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Photos View Cell Identifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIButton *imageButton;
    imageButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kImageButton_TAG];
    ALAsset *imageAsset = [[[[OrderManager sharedOrderManager] currentOrder] assets] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    [imageButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset aspectRatioThumbnail]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return cell;
}
```

Of course, being that the delegate no longer exists, and the delegate is the owner of the asset, `*imageAsset` is now a nil pointer.
My question is, how do I make either my table view controller or my `sharedOrderManager` the owner of the ALAsset?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm using ARC.

Comment: something isn't right here... adding an object to an array will increment the retain count, preventing it from being deallocated. Additionally, even if the object you added was somehow deallocated, your singleton's reference to it would not be nil - it would be a pointer to an invalid reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that `NSMutableArray*` returned by `assets` has been initialized (probably at singleton implementation or any other method called after it).

Looks like it is `nil` and not `addObject:` nor `objectAtIndex:` could return anything. `NSMutableArray` retains the added objects, they should not be released until you overrelease it yourself.

Comment: Oh durr. Out of all the objects in my singleton, that specific array was the only one not `alloc/init`'d. Cheers!